# Prove inequation related to pythagoras theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, problem-solving

$\sqrt {A^2+(N*A)^2}+\sqrt {B^2+(N*B)^2}<\sqrt {A^2+(N*A+M)^2}+\sqrt {B^2+(N*B-M)^2}$

Where $A$ and $B$ are positive real numbers, and $N$ and $M$ are real numbers, also $M\neq0$
[image]

I and J are segments that end in a single point on the lowest segment, and start at the top of A and B

[image]

$I+J$ is equal to the left side of the inequation, and has the lowest value possible given the length of the lowest segment, the length of $A$ and the length of $B$, i want to prove that $I+J$ is minimal

Comment: I don't understand. If $M\le 0$ then the inequality is false, and if $M>0$, then it is obvious. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: oh i had a typo sorry

Comment: Still not clear.  With $M=0$ the claim is false.  With $M\neq 0$ this is just repeating the claim that $I+J$ is minimal.

Comment: i want to prove that I+J is minimal, also i forgot to mention that M does not equal 0

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  If you are trying to prove that $I+J$ is minimal you'll have to explain how the segments $I,J$ are constructed.

Comment: @lulu There is nothing to explain. What's not clear to you?

Comment: @amsmath  How are $I,J$ defined?  I assumed that they were defined to be such that the sum was minimal, but that doesn't make sense if the goal is to prove that the sum is minimal.

Comment: @lulu $I+J$ is obviously the left-hand side of the inequality (look at the picture). The LHS is supposed to be the minimum of the RHS.

Comment: @amsmath  But the inequality is literally the statement that $I+J$ is minimal.  Moving the contact point on the lower segment by $M$ just gives you the right hand of the inequality.

Comment: the inequality is an algebraic representation of the problem below which is: prove that if A/B=(A*N)/(B*N) (which are the names of the lowes segments) then I+J is minimal, i want to solve that problem, which is proving that the inequality is true

Comment: @SartemCacartem , if you make a comment but do not begin it with an at sign and the start of a user name, people who have left to view other questions will not be notified. Meanwhile, you have an answer by Ted Shifrin. Ted was asking you for clarification above. His answer should help guide  you

Comment: If I set $B=A$, I get that the inequality is equivalent to $M<2A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is valid if and only if the angles formed at the horizontal line segment are equal, which, in fact, they are. You can prove the inequality by reflecting the second segment across the horizontal and observing that the path from the upper vertex to the (reflected) lower vertex is shortest when you have the straight line segment joining them. This happens precisely when those angles are equal.

**COMMENT**: If you labeled the upper left vertex $E$, the right vertex $F$, the point on the horizontal $G$, and the reflected right vertex $F'$, then my statement says that $EG + GF'$ is smallest when $G$ lies on the line segment $\overline{EF'}$.

Comment: i tried to visualize your answer but i dont know why exactly  +′  is smallest when  lies on the line segment '

Comment: Informally, the shortest distance from $E$ to $F'$ is given by the line segment joining them. More formally, the sum of the lengths of two sides of a triangle is always longer than the length of the remaining side. (Apply this when $G$ is *not* on the line segment joining $E$ and $F'$.)